# Execute a program with root during runtime

Tags: c++, linux

I have a C++ program that needs root privileges for executing some functions. If I run my compiled code in su mode like

```
linux-c5b6:/home/suman #
```

It satisfies my requirement, but at run time I want to check whether my process has root privilege or not. If not then it will take su password from user and run my code for correct results.

Answer (score 2):

The *geteuid(2)* system call will return the effective user ID of the user running your program:

```
if (geteuid() == 0) {
    // running as root
} else {
    // not running as root
}
```

Rather than have the program ask the user for the root password, I would recommend that it exit with an error message and instruct the user to re-run the program with `sudo`.

Comment: you are right , but I already tried that , but I saw a sw where during launching that sw it checks whether it has su privilege or not, if not then that take su password from user and execute the program in su mode.I want to implement the same thing.

Comment: I know, I just think that's generally a very bad idea. The system provides a rich framework for giving users escalated privileges. It's better to use it than to try to reinvent it badly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the current UID shell environment variable, only root will be UID=0

Or, better yet, query the current user and check their UID directly using the system password library functions.